# Why does XGBoost only support binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I have noticed that the implementations for XGBoost both in Python and R support only binary classification of a categorical target variable.

- I have implemented both Random Forest and Extremely Randomised Trees for my classification problem

**Why can I not use this method to classify targets coming from multiple categories?**

**Are there adjustments that can be made to my multiclass dataset in order to use XGBoost?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does support multi class classification. Below is the code:

```
param = {
    'max_depth': 3,  # the maximum depth of each tree
    'eta': 0.3,  # the training step for each iteration
    'silent': 1,  # logging mode - quiet
    'objective': 'multi:softprob',  # error evaluation for multiclass training
    'num_class': 3}  # the number of classes that exist in this dataset
```

You can use `num_class` as parameter in Python for Multi Class Classification.

Answer (score 3):

From the [XGboost documentation page](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html):

Specify the learning task and the corresponding learning objective. 
The objective options are below:

- **objective [default=reg:squarederror]**

  - [...]
  - multi:softmax: set XGBoost to do multiclass classification using the softmax objective, you also need to set num_class(number of classes)
  - multi:softprob: same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata * nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata * nclass matrix. The result contains predicted probability of each data point belonging to each class.
  - [...]
- **eval_metric [default according to objective]**

  - [...]
  - merror: Multiclass classification error rate. It is calculated as #(wrong cases)/#(all cases).
  - mlogloss: Multiclass logloss.

Looks like there are quite some options for multiclass classification, just choose your weapon :)